# Button with a dropdown for .NET?

Tags: .net, winforms, button, visual-studio-2017, controls

I'm looking for something similar to this button that was available in vb6:

[image]

(The above was called "MyButton" in vb6 [Active-x control?] and you just set its AppearanceMode property to DropDown Mode)

Just a button that has a dropdown to the right side of it. The closest I could find in the standard Visual Studio 2017 toolbox is the ToolStrip (`System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip` class), but its appearance doesn't really jive with the rest of my Winforms applications.

Comment: I think the closest native control is a combobox with dropdownstyle set to dropdownlist...unless you want to dive into modifying its graphics paint or creating your own usercontrol that may be about as close as you can get

Comment: I once created my own control just like this, there are no standard options available.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad How so? It looks like creating a user control is my best and simplest option. Kind of a pain though.

Answer (score 0):

It's called `SplitButton` available in all Visual Studio.

Comment: Using VS2022, under All Windows Forms controls, I see SplitContainer and Splitter, no SplitButton. Can you confirm you're not referring to a 3rd party control you have installed on your dev machine?